React Native init project with template typescript take so much time
I'm trying to create a React Native project with template typescript by this command
npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript

And I saw that it run into this step:

May I ask that why it take so long (with me is more than 2 hour) to process this template.
I've tried to look into this document (https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript) but cannot find any related to my question.
Thanks for your help.

npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript --npm
Can you try this way? It worked for me.

Hi @MertCelik, yes it does faster (only a few minutes). Thank you so much!
